# How to animate a 9 slice in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, resize, size, sprite

I want to animate a **9 slice** and *simply* want for me to just put in a *speed value* with a value of how big I want for it to become on *specific axes* just in a **parameter**.
But when I *tried* using SpriteRenderer.size += Vector2(something, something) its moves **buggily**, has an *inconsistent speed growth*, and sometimes goes far above the *threshold* and then snaps back.
Any *idea* how to fix *this*?

**Keep** in *mind* I'm *pretty* new to **IEnumerators and coding and unity** in *general* so be nice lel

```
 public IEnumerator BarSize(float speed , float XToSize, float YToSize)
    {
        while(true)
        {
            for(float i = Sprite.size.x; 1 != XToSize; i = Sprite.size.x)
            {
                Sprite.size += new Vector2(speed, 0);

                if(i >= XToSize)
                {
                    Sprite.size = new Vector2(XToSize, Sprite.size.y);

                    yield break;
                }

                yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();
            }
            
            for (float i = Sprite.size.x; 1 != XToSize; i = Sprite.size.x)
            {
                Sprite.size += new Vector2(0, speed);

                if (Sprite.size.y >= YToSize)
                {
                    Sprite.size = new Vector2(transform.localScale.x, YToSize);

                    yield break;
                }

                yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
            }

            if (Sprite.size == new Vector2(XToSize, YToSize))
            {
                yield break;
            }

            yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am *an* **IDIOT!!!** I **FORGOT** to use `WaitForFixedUpdate()` and used the situationally worse `WaitForEndOfFrame()`. Lmao **EVERYTHING** works now.